# React Router v4 rendering component twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Here is my Router Implementation

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={ProfilesIndex} />
    <Route exact path="/profiles" component={ProfilesIndex} />
    <Route exact path="/profiles/new" component={ProfileEditor} />
    <Route exact path="/profiles/:id" component={ProfileEditor} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When I am browsing to `/profiles/new` path, it is rendering the ProfileEditor component twice. For every other route, it is working fine.

Can someone suggest how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer after browsing into multiple sections in [Router Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch). Problem was it was matching multiple routes

When user opens `/profiles/new` it matches two routes

1. /routes/new
2. /routes/:id

Because :id is like a wildcard * and it also matches `new` word so both routes get matched and hence the component gets rendered twice.

The solution is to wrap the routes with `Switch` if you do not want to match multiple routes.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={ProfilesIndex} />
    <Route exact path="/profiles" component={ProfilesIndex} />
    <Route exact path="/profiles/new" component={ProfileEditor} />
    <Route exact path="/profiles/:id" component={ProfileEditor} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me.

Comment: I had the same problem, but with `<Outlet />` from React Router 6, which renders the "nested" component along with the base component

Comment: Can there only be one wildcard inside the switch?

Answer (score 13):

for me, this is because of `React.StrictNode` which is wrapped arround App component.

it intentionally double render components (only in development) to enforce you, not use side effects on some of your component's
lifecycle events.

the reason behind that is documented  [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

Comment: React wtf, really )

Answer (score 8):

For anyone coming here from v6+

`exact` prop no longer exists, the paths are exact by default if they aren't appended a wildcard `*`

However I was still getting a double render. I ran a prod build and checked and the double render is gone so probably nothing to worry about - sometimes hooks run twice in development mode (I guess that's what's happening internally)

Comment: I just tested it, you are right. I'm still curious about why it happens in development though.

Comment: @XavierMukodi, just like AmirHossein mentioned, its expected behaviour in developer mode when using strict mode. Details are explained https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects